# Error **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** error while uploading files to AWS S3 using multipart upload and Pre-Signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, connection-reset

Trying to upload large files using multipart upload where I generate pre-signed URL for each chunk and the push files to S3. When I upload large files for some of the chunks I'm getting '**net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**' intermittently and the upload is getting failed. Is there any way to over come this ? or Do I need to configure anything on AWS so that this issue will not occur ? Any suggestions are really appreciated. Also are there any ways to make the file upload successful(like retrying to upload the failed chunk again) ? [Attaching screenshot of network calls while uploading a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEPk.jpg)

Note: The expiry time set for pre-signed URL is 60 minutes.

I am using NodeJS as backend where I have API's to generate Upload Id, Pre-Signed URL from AWS etc and the UI is built on Next JS, where I am using pre-signed URL to upload the file to AWS.